# C++ Builder TTabControl tabs displayed right to left

Tags: c++builder

I put a `TTabControl` on a `TForm` in C++Builder VCL, but I can't find any right-to-left options in the Form's properties or the `TTabControl`'s properties to set tabs from left to right, like in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: In visual studio, in TabControl properties, you can change RightToLeftLayout field value to True of False that make change tabs position to left or right.

Comment: You are referring to WinForm's [Bi-directional support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/bi-directional-support-for-windows-forms-applications). Setting `RightToLeft=Yes` and `RightToLeftLayout=true` makes a `TabControl` "mirror" itself (internally, it enables the  `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` and `WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT` window styles, and disables the `WS_EX_RTLREADING`, `WS_EX_RIGHT`, and `WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR` window styles) ...

Comment: ... Delphi/C++Builder VCL controls have `BiDiMode` properties for that purpose, but for a `TTabControl` some manual work is needed, see [TTabControl: tabs displayed right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888239/).

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau
Thank you.